# Can we kill (and possibly blacklist) [php]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, blacklist

PHP is a scripting language for building dynamic web sites and web apps.

This site is not about building web apps.

I've been looking through [php](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) and any question that's not already closed should be or really isn't about PHP at all.

Can this tag please be burninated?

Can we also consider this tag for the black list?

Answer (score 3):

In the first instance we need to try and remove the tag from the system. In this case the way to do this would be to delete the questions as they are really so far off topic there's no way they could be edited into shape.

Then once that's done we can request the blacklist.

Comment: I have been wearing out my "Delete" button.

Comment: I currently see no questions tagged [tag:php].